# how much THD do I expect on a 32 bits float sine waveform?

Tags: embedded, signal-processing, stm32, cmsis

I'm using a stm32f411 uC to generate a sine wave using cmsis dsp libary
The sine waveform is used to feed an audiocodec by I2S inteface
I notice so much harmonics on the analog output f the codec
I thiking on how much THD do my waveform have
thank

EDIT the sine wave form is the one on Cmsis dsp library
https://github.com/mikeferguson/stm32/blob/master/libraries/CMSIS/DSP_Lib/FastMathFunctions/arm_sin_f32.c
I just need the harmonics added by digital sine waveform
I'm thinking on create an array of sine values created from that function and analize it on matlab

Comment: 32-bit floating point is as good as any CD or MP3 player, but the quality also depends on the sample rate.

Comment: This question is probably OT for SO.  It is also probably impossible to answer from the information given since contributors to THD will be the quantisation error, the quantisation noise, the precision of sine function used and the effect of any external analogue filtering performed.

Comment: I would like to know about quantisation error, quantisation noise, and precision of sine function How much harmonics they add to the system I don't care about analog part of the problem just the digital sine waveform created from this function https://github.com/mikeferguson/stm32/blob/master/libraries/CMSIS/DSP_Lib/FastMathFunctions/arm_sin_f32.c

Answer (score 0):

How much quantization noise and THD a given tone generator adds, depends entirely on it's implementation details and it is not straight forward to derive. As you also suggest, analyzing the output in Matlab or similar is one way to do it. Alternatively, if you only care about whether or not it is your generator or analog parts that are to be blamed, then an easier approach might be to generate a simple sine that is a fraction of your sample frequency. This can be done without the fancy CMSIS library by simply pre-calculating an array of e.g eight samples in Matlab for a sine with a frequency of fs/8. Then do your THD measurements again. If the THD is still big, then your CMSIS generator is not to blame.

Regards
Klaus